# while trainig my model got an error "Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int)"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I know there are ans to the following q but none of them working for me. so could someone help me?
context:-
I was coding a neural net and I was getting an error "Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int)"
this model was made to predict based on user-provided 7 values and would predict 4 values.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import warnings
import pickle
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib as mp
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from keras import Sequential
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow import keras
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
###########################imports done#############################################

data = pd.read_csv("datset.csv")


#################### data imported ################################################
label_encode = {"City": {'Ahmedabad':0,'Aizawl':1, 'Amaravati':2, 'Amritsar':3, 'Bengaluru':4, 'Bhopal':5,'Brajrajnagar':6, 'Chandigarh':7, 'Chennai':8, 'Coimbatore':9, 'Delhi':10, 'Ernakulam':11,'Gurugram':12, 'Guwahati':13, 'Hyderabad':14, 'Jaipur':15, 'Jorapokhar':16, 'Kochi':17 ,'Kolkata':18,'Lucknow':19, 'Mumbai':20 ,'Patna':21, 'Shillong':22, 'Talcher':23, 'Thiruvananthapuram':24,'Visakhapatnam':25}}

data.replace(label_encode,inplace=True)
abel_encode = {"Region": {'5. Western' :0,'2. North Eastern':1, '1. Northern':2 ,'6. Southern':3, '3. Central':4,'4. Eastern':5}}

data.replace(label_encode,inplace=True)
label_encode = {"State": {'Gujarat':0, 'Mizoram':1 ,'Andhra Pradesh':2 ,'Punjab':3, 'Karnataka':4,'Madhya Pradesh':5, 'Odisha':6, 'Chandigarh':7, 'Tamil Nadu':8, 'Delhi':9 ,'Kerala':10,'Haryana':11, 'Assam':12 ,'Telangana':13, 'Rajasthan':14 ,'Jharkhand':15, 'West Bengal':16,'Uttar Pradesh':17, 'Maharashtra':18, 'Bihar':19, 'Meghalaya':20}}

data.replace(label_encode,inplace=True)
label_encode = {"Month": {'01. Jan':1, '02. Feb':2, '03. Mar':3, '04. Apr':4, '05. May':5, '06. Jun':6, '07. Jul':7,'08. Aug':8, '09. Sep':9 ,'10. Oct':10, '11. Nov':11, '12. Dec':12}}

data.replace(label_encode,inplace=True)
label_encode = {"Season": {'1. Winter':0, '2. Summer':1, '3. Monsoon':2, '4. Post-Monsoon':3}}

data.replace(label_encode,inplace=True)
label_encode = {"Weekday_or_weekend": {'Weekday':0, 'Weekend':1}}

data.replace(label_encode,inplace=True)

########################values replaced############################################
x_values = data[['City','State','Region','Month','Year','Season','Weekday_or_weekend']]
y_values = data[['PM2.5','CO','SO2','AQI']]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_values,y_values,test_size=0.15,random_state=1)


###################values split ###################################################
log_reg = Sequential()

log_reg.add(Dense(10,input_dim=7,activation='relu'))

log_reg.add(Dense(20,activation='relu'))
log_reg.add(Dense(10,activation='relu'))

log_reg.add(Dense(4,kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))

log_reg.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
log_reg.summary()
log_reg.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=10,shuffle=True,batch_size=3)

####################### model made ###################################################
pickle.dump(log_reg,open('model.pkl','wb'))
model=pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))


#*********************** end ****************
```

when I try to do this `data = data.astype(float)`
I get an error ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Unknown'
when I try to do this `data = data.astype(int)`
I get an error pandas.errors.IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

full traceback :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kani2\Desktop\Forest-Fire-Prediction-Website-master\forest_fire.py", line 61, in <module>
    log_reg.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=10,shuffle=True,batch_size=3)
  File "C:\Users\kani2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\kani2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 102, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).
```

Comment: Could you post a few rows of your csv file, please?

Comment: Full traceback please!  I believe dataframe values are first converted to numpy arrays, and the array has to be float, or convertible to float.  It's your responsibility to ensure that the `data` matches the tensorflow expectations.  The errors are a big confusing, but it looks like you have strings in `data`.

Comment: Some of your columns still contain non numeric values. first, check if all the replace you are doing are working, then, to check if there are more values to be converted, use pandas.to_numeric, if it converts the desired column to numeric that that column is good. Otherwise, pandas.to_numeric will return which column could be not converted and will show in the error the string or object causing issues and then replace it.